# Do Aes Sedai wear tallitot?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time, inspiration

The [tallit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallit) is a Jewish garb, which has a lot of resemblance to the Aes Sedai shawl:

- It's a shawl
- It's got fringes
- The fringes are (or at least *were*) dyed blue

However, I couldn't find any reference to this, and the books' cover art seems to disprove the idea (although it makes sense not to use actual Jewish themes for non-Jewish book covers).

And even if the shawl isn't an actual tallit, is it at least based on the tallit?

Is there any actual data on this, beyond mere guesswork?

Comment: Most of the book covers were not good reference guides.

Comment: @Radhil So you can't judge a book by its cover, eh?

Comment: Gevalt, those Cenotians get around everywhere don't they? :)

Comment: One small correction, the fringes aren't dyed blue except for the Blue Ajah. They're always dyed in the color of the owners Ajah.

Comment: @Paul I guess Jews are Blues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shawls are not really described to that extent.  In the Wheel Of Time, our time's influence on their time is minute at best, just as their time's influence on hours is minute at best.

Comment: I can't tell if that is a typo at the end of the last sentence or just a clever quip. =]